# Doctrine accociation mappings - a real life scenario

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, associations

I am currently setting up association mappings in the Doctrine ORM working with Symfony 2 on an event management application. I find it a bit confusing to grab the concept, so I would appreciate if you could tell me what two mappings are required in the following cases:

There are users (User entity) and Events (Event entity) in the application.

**1. (First mapping)**

One user can be an attendee of many events / an event holds many users as attendees.

**2. (Second mapping)**

Each event has only one User owner (a user that set up the event), but each user can be an owner of many events

My assumption is the following:

**Ad.1**

Here a **ManytoMany bidirectional** association is required since the User entity holds `$events`, while the Event entity holds `$attendees` (both are mapped to each other)

**Ad.2**

Here **ManytoOne unidirectional** association is required since since the Event entity holds `$owner`, while the User entity does not have to map to the Event.

I will appreciate your feedback greatly. I am sure it will help me understand the concept better.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, just be careful when working with ManyToMany on Doctrine.
Doctrine will automaticaly handle it, but be aware that if you have any extra columns on the many to many association (besides of attendee id and event id), you'll need to handle the ManyToMany as another entity itself.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that another entity will be required to handle the extra table.